# sending parameters to stored procedure error

Tags: c#, sql

I can't send a parameter to stored procedure cause it's creating an error Procedure or function 'f1findproductbynme' expects parameter '@product_name', which was not supplied.'
kindly look at my code. Thanks

```
        f1consql.Open();
        SqlCommand sqlfindprod = new SqlCommand("f1findproductbynme", f1consql);
        sqlfindprod.Parameters.AddWithValue("@product_name", rcvfindprodnme);
        sqlfindprod.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlDataReader readbycolumn = sqlfindprod.ExecuteReader();
        while (readbycolumn.Read())
        {
            txtf3productnme.Text = (readbycolumn["Product_Details.Name"].ToString());
            txtf1Qty.Text = (readbycolumn["Product_Details.Unit_Price"].ToString());
        }
        readbycolumn.Close();
```

Comment: also add your "Stored Procedure"

Comment: You need to set the command type.

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks my friend. I forgot that thing